# Flash Builder (Zend Studio) using SVN with Local Sources

Tags: eclipse, svn, zend-studio

When I first installed the Flash Builder 4.5 trial and created a new project from existing sources which happened to be an svn repository checked out to my local web server, I had svn info including revision number and the ability to right-click to svn tools in the PHP Explorer View.  At some time this disappeared in the last few weeks, now I need to go back to the folder (in Windows) containing the working copy to perform an update, commit, or to browse the log.

I have the default Zend Studio installation and then I tried to fix this by installing subclipse from  http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x, that hasn't worked either.
I have tried going thru every Preference I could think of.

I do not want to use subclipse to check-out because I want to save them to a specific path that I have in my virtual hosts file for my local Apache server.

Any thoughts on how to turn this behavior back on?